# Segmentation Fault 11 in C File I/O

Tags: c

I'm writing a function which searches a text file formatted like this:

*#User1\pass\*
*#User2\pass\*
*#User3\pass\*

I have written the function Check_User:

```
int Check_User(char input[20], FILE *userlist)
{
    int c, i;
    fseek(userlist, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(1)
    {
        while((c = fgetc(userlist)) != '#')
        {
            if(c == EOF)
                return 1;
        }
        while(input[i] == (c = fgetc(userlist)))
        {
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        if(c == '\\')
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Which is called from here:

```
while(Check_User(username, userlist) == 0)
{
    printf("Username already in use. Please select another:");
    Get_Input(username);
}
```

Check user checks the file pointed to by *userlist to see if the username[20] contains a username which is already in use.  If it is already in use it calls Get_Input for a new username.

The program makes it all the way to the while loop and then gives me a segmentation fault: 11.  I have read that this often stems from trying to write beyond the end of an array, or generally doing things to memory you don't have access to.  Userlist.txt has been opened in r+ mode.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: (1) are you sure the fopen succeeds?  you do need to check to make sure that `userlist` is not-null     (2) i was never initialized prior to use.

Comment: Looks like it was because i had not been initialized.  Woops, haha. I feel a bit silly for missing that. Oh well, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not initialize your variable `i` before its first use. In C, declared variables are not initialized to numerical 0 (as they would be in C# or Java), but simply use the value that was present at their memory location before. Thus, the value of `i` may be far bigger that the length of the string `input`, and `input[i]` may access an invalid memory location.

As a side note: to quickly debug this yourself under Linux, compile the program with debug symbols (`gcc -g`) and then use `valgrind --tool=memcheck <your program>` to let valgrind find the source of error for you.